# Allow contributor role to upload images and not edit already published articles

Tags: images, uploads, user-roles

I have the following two requirements:

1. I want to allow users with the contributor role to upload media (images mostly) in their posts and preferably they shouldn't be able to delete existing ones before submitting it for review.
2. I want to make sure once an article is published that it can't be edited by the  contributor (the writer of the plugin with user role contributor) or if it can be edited the newer version isn't updated before going through a submission process.

I was recommended the [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper) plugin but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Any information about any other plugin or how to do this in Role Scoper would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do all of this using the [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin. I normally tend to avoid answering questions by linking directly to a plugin but in this case, what you need comes in this package.

Comment: You are welcome. And please let us know if you have any further questions around this subject. I run a multiple author platform myself where I use similar features so I am very familiar with this territory.

Comment: i have actually.if we give access to upload media to contributors it implies that they have option to delete it as well . Is there any way that they are allowed to upload files but not delete or edit them to safeguard the data.
secondly i mentioned this before also . By default the contributors are allowed to edit the posts once they are published. This results in a problem thiat is they can change something if the contributor feels so and that will we updated in the post. i would love a functionality that post,s edited version has to be approved again while the original version still visible

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to prevent a user from deleting an image (file) they personally uploaded. I would suggest starting a new question for the best support.

Comment: @Danny are you asking a feature that stops the user from deleting a published post? If you post a new question I can answer that for you :)

Comment: not exactly.. ill post a new question and invite you to it ... ill post the link over here in comments only

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77651/reapproval-for-edits-and-deletion-after-post-is-published

here sorry it took so long

Answer (score 13):

For image upload option to contributors

Add this code in your current theme's `functions.php`

```
if ( current_user_can('contributor') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
    add_action('admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads');
function allow_contributor_uploads() {
    $contributor = get_role('contributor');
    $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
}
```

Comment: After Codex: "While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results." (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)