# Using WordPress’s add_cap method to Allow Contributors to Upload Media is not Working

Tags: uploads

I would like to allow contributors to upload media by using the following code added to `functions.php`. But the Add Media Button still doesn't show up.

```php
// Allow Contributors to Add Media
if ( current_user_can('contributor') && ! current_user_can('upload_files') ) {
    add_action('admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads');
    function allow_contributor_uploads() {
       $contributor = get_role('contributor');
       $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow contributor role to upload images and not edit already published articles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77613/allow-contributor-role-to-upload-images-and-not-edit-already-published-articles)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `current_user_can('contributor')` to `current_user_can('edit_posts')`. According to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Notes), 'Passing role names to current_user_can() is discouraged as this is not guaranteed to work correctly.'

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working.

Comment: Then I would try surrounding your conditional expression in brackets, just to make sure it's getting parsed properly:

Answer (score 0):

I would try surrounding your conditional expression in brackets, just to make sure it's getting parsed properly:

`if ( current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('upload_files') ) {
  add_action( 'admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads' );
}
function allow_contributor_uploads() {
  $contributor = get_role('contributor');
  $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
}`

Comment: No, not working for me. You can try at your side.